# Ошибка в коде python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Я пишу скрипт который будет заменять слово в файле на вводимое пользователем.
Скрипт:

```
print "enter your text"
newText = input("#")
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    old_data = f.read()

new_data = old_data.replace('oldtext', (newText))

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_data)
```

После того как я введу любую цифру

> TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: В чем возникла проблема? Какое сообщение об ошибке выводится?

Comment: TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
после того как я введу любую цифру

Comment: Возможно стоит убрать скобки: `new_data = old_data.replace('oldtext', newText)`

Comment: я пробовал но ошибка та же

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки. На какую конкретно строку ругается?

Comment: Интересно.. попробуйте `newText = raw_input("#")`. В питоне2 `input` это `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, так что результат будет интерпретироваться в зависимости от ввода, а в `newText` должна быть строка

Comment: спасибо огромное! помогло!

Answer (score 3):

Замените:

```
newText = input("#")
```

на:

```
newText = raw_input("#")
```

Причина в том, что [input(prompt)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) на самом деле выполняется как `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, из-за можно получить не строку, а другой тип