# SyntaxError в stdin при использовании input()

Tags: python, python-2.x

Пытаюсь просто вывести вводимую строку, но почему-то получаю SyntaxError с указанием на содержимое stdin, а не кода. Что я делаю не так??

Код: https://ideone.com/axY1CR

```
print input()
```

stdin:

```
10 20 30
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    10 20 30
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: raw_input() . .

Comment: @andreymal, да, так работает. А можно поподробнее и ответом?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/901669

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С самого начала в Python присутствовали две функции: `raw_input`, которая читает строку из stdin, и `input`, которая [примерно](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node26.html#1507) эквивалентна `eval(raw_input())`.

К Python 3 решили, что так жить нельзя, и функцию `input` выкинули, а `raw_input` [переименовали](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/) в `input`.

В итоге в третьем питоне такой ввод для `input()` выдаст строку `'10 20 30'`, а второй питон не сможет выполнить эту строку как код и выдаст синтаксическую ошибку — вместо этого нужно использовать `raw_input()`.

Библиотека [six](https://six.readthedocs.io/) для удобства разработки предоставляет алиас `six.input()`, который ссылается на `input()` в Python 3 и на `raw_input()` в Python 2.

Comment: Мда, вместо одного слова целую библиотеку написали... И чего я не удивлён? Хотя, она, похоже, полно всего делает, но как-то странно...